# Why are my emails with .pdf attachments and sent via SF are converted to .html files?

Tags: email, attachment, html, pdf

Why my emails with attachments are converted from PDF to HTML?
The email I've sent had only 1 attachments 1MB so why it is converted from PDF to HTML?
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending mass emails, attachments are always converted to links. This is explained in [Email attachments sent as HTML file links](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000025280&type=1):

> ## HTML links in Mass Emails
>
> - All e-mail templates with attachments will come in as .html files.